# Clone form textarea first 255 character on submission jQuery form validation

Tags: jquery, forms

I use jQuery form validation for my forms.

I have a problem with CRM system recording first 255 in long message form submissions. If less than 255, it records, but doesn't when greater than 255.

So I need help on cloning the **first 255** char of input longmsg to shortened-clone textarea in a hidden way. Is it possible?

Area for people to input:

```
<textarea name="longmsg" rows="8" cols="45" id="longmsg" class="required" placeholder="What would you like to say?" maxlength="1050"></textarea>
```

Clone the first 255 char to this hidden textarea on form submission:

```
<textarea name="shortened-clone" rows="8" cols="45" id="shortened-clone"  placeholder="What would you like to say?" type="hidden"></textarea>
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use substring. So

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    $('#shortened-clone').val($('#longmsg').val().substr(0,255));
});
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/oehy2brm/)